# Fixing the size of textView of JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have tried changing the code below , commenting the textContainerInset And the contentInset , not able to find out how the container's frame changes when i add text , there appears to be nothing in the delegates of textView as well.

```
- (void)jsq_configureTextView
{
   [self setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    CGFloat cornerRadius = 6.0f;

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;

    self.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(cornerRadius, 0.0f, cornerRadius, 0.0f);

    self.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(4.0f, 2.0f, 4.0f, 2.0f);
    self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    self.scrollEnabled = YES;

    self.scrollsToTop = NO;
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    self.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
    self.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;

    self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
    self.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
    self.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault;
    self.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    self.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;

    self.text = nil;

    _placeHolder = nil;
    _placeHolderTextColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    [self jsq_addTextViewNotificationObservers];
}
```

Comment: you want to change the font for input text in JSQMessageTextView?

Comment: No i want that the textView to not to resize on addittion or deletion of text in it, as well the the whole contentView (with left accessory button and right send button ) to not to update frames to increase the height .

Comment: @SouravSachdeva Did you find solution for your problem? Because I am facing same.

Comment: @CodeHunter  I don’t remember what way I used it but I ended up setting maximumHeight I mentioned in the answer

Comment: Actually when I do use your answer then it works only first time then if I type second message it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @CodeHunter ohh I see I can’t test it now as I don’t have that code now.

Comment: @SouravSachdeva Can I share with you so you can look into my code.

Comment: @CodeHunter sorry I am afraid I won’t be able to do that now I’m busy these days and don’t do much iOS stuff  ,you can frame your question better and post it on stack that will be better

Comment: @SouravSachdeva Ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the maximumHeight of inputToolbar of JSQMessagesViewController would suffice .

self.inputToolbar.maximumHeight = 44